# Could we Bose-condense Higgs bosons?

Tags: higgs, bose-einstein-condensate

Apart from the obvious problem that we'd have to create enough of them and somehow not let them decay, is there anything that would prevent a Higgs boson condensate?

Comment: Why not? Folks have demonstrated bose-like condensation of fermionic particles ( $He_3$ for example will pair-up to form bosonic units), for one thing.  Disclaimer: I know very little about Higgs particles, so for all I know they're always in a condensate state.

Comment: @count_to_10 but surely the particles itself are much more energetic than that?

Comment: In a sense the Higgs field itself is a condensate, or rather the result of a tachyon condensation driving the electroweak symmetry breaking, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_mechanism and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyon_condensation.